# rails nils in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, null

This is probably a simple question, but I noticed a few errors deriving from having empty values instead of nils...

If a user leaves a field blank in a standard rails app is there a way to leave the field in the database set to NULL instead of entering an empty value?

Basically so a check like @model.info.nil? return true instead of having to check if it is both nil and empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use var.blank?, because I get these results in a Rails 3 console running against Ruby 1.8:

```
>> nil.blank?
=> true
>> [].blank?
=> true
>> nil.empty?
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?
        from (irb):4
```

Historically, I haven't seen .empty? work for nil objects.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** As *brokenbeatnik* noted, I confused `blank?` with `empty?`, my bad.

You don't have to check *both* nil and empty values. `var.empty?` will return `true` even for nil (see API docs).  So, I usually find it more convenient to use empty check only.

But if you don't want that, you can convert empty values to nils with [active record callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). Something like `attribute = nil if attribute.empty?` each time before object is saved.